# MS Access Max and Select top n query issue with duplicate values

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

This is my very first post, so hopefully I did not break any rules.

I am an MS Access newbie and my sql knowledge is limited at best.  I am trying to write a query that will return the top 3 test scores for a given student.  My tables looks like the following:

```
Student ID    Test ID      Score
1                1           95
1                2           90
1                3           90
1                4           90
2                1           99
2                2           95
2                3           90
2                4           90
```

Through research on this forum, I've been able to find some very helpful code that basically does what I'm looking for EXCEPT when I have multiple test scores that are the same value.  In that situation, I get more than the top 3 scores.  So in the case of student #1, the query will return all 4 test scores, not just the first 3.  I tried adding a unique index field to order by but had no luck.  So far, my code is as follows:

```sql
SELECT MyTable.StudentID, MyTable.TestID, Max(MyTable.TestScore) AS MaxOfTestScore
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.StudentID, MyTable.TestID, MyTable.TestScore
HAVING MyTable.TestScore In (SELECT TOP 3 TestScore FROM MyTable T2 WHERE 
MyTable.StudentID = T2.StudentID ORDER BY TestScore DESC)
ORDER BY MyTable.StudentID, MyTable.TestScore DESC;
```

Credit goes to Sarkazein for providing this code so far.  I tried to comment on that thread but couldn't since I don't have any reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT StudentID, TestID, TestScore
  FROM MyTable t
 WHERE TestID IN
(
  SELECT TOP 3 TestID 
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID 
   ORDER BY TestScore DESC, TestID
)
 ORDER BY StudentID, TestScore DESC, TestID;
```

Output:

```
| STUDENTID | TESTID | TESTSCORE |
|-----------|--------|-----------|
|         1 |      1 |        95 |
|         1 |      2 |        90 |
|         1 |      3 |        90 |
|         2 |      1 |        99 |
|         2 |      2 |        95 |
|         2 |      3 |        90 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b731/6)** demo. *It's for SQL Server, but I believe should work in MS Access*

**UPDATE** It's been tested on MS Access and it works as expected without any modifications.

[image: Results in MS Access]

Comment: Thanks Peterm.  That seems to be what I'm looking for, however, I can't get that code to work in MS Access.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're quite welcome. I've just tested in MS Access on my machine. It works as expected without any modifications. So most likely you're doing something wrong. Explain exactly what happens when you try to run it. I get unexpected results you get an error (then what error) etc?

Comment: You are right!!  I just tried it again and it worked this time.  I guess I must have gotten some typo.  I used the student test example to make it easier to explain and I guess I messed something up when I did a search and replace for the field names.  Thank you so much!  You have been very helpful!

Comment: I just noticed something else.  When I go back and look at the query in design view, I noticed the table changed from MyTable to "t".  I don't know enough about sql to know what is the significance here.  If I added "MyTable." before each field in the code, would that impact anything?  That maybe what I did wrong before.