# Filtering duplicates from query using complex (NOT MAX) criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with multiple records for some customers, where their address changes the database adds a new record, same customer ID number, but new 'ADDCDE' with a higher index number.

e.g.

```
NAME         UNIQUEID     ADDCDE  ADDRESS

Customer A   ID123        Z1      Address1 Town1 City1
Customer A   ID123        Z2      Address2 Town2 City2
Customer A   ID123        Z3      Address3 Town3 City3
Customer B   ID1234       Z1      Address1 Town1 City1
Customer C   ID12345      Z1      Address1 Town1 City1
Customer C   ID12345      Z2      Address2 Town2 City2
```

I've been able to identify all the duplicate records using query wizard,
but what I would really like to do is remove ALL BUT the "Max" record of ADDCDE, so in this instance removing from the above records to leave the following.

```
NAME         UNIQUEID     ADDCDE  ADDRESS

Customer A   ID123        Z3      Address3 Town3 City3
Customer B   ID1234       Z1      Address1 Town1 City1
Customer C   ID12345      Z2      Address2 Town2 City2
```

I'm a newbie to SQL, am mostly using the Access Query design builder but if anyone can answer this query somehow (because I need to do this often), I will figure out how and where to put it and make it work!

Comment: Do you have anything that indicates the order of insertion of the new records?

Comment: The `ADDCDE` column, from the way I read the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access Max and Select top n query issue with duplicate values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822809/ms-access-max-and-select-top-n-query-issue-with-duplicate-values)

Comment: Is it possible there could be more than 9 ADDCDE values for one customer?  If so, the text value 'Z10' will be evaluated as "less than" the text value 'Z9'.  And it would be easier to make ADDCDE a plain number field.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all but the most recent address code using a correlated subquery:

```
delete from t
    where t.addcde < (select max(t2.addcde) from t t2 where t2.uniqueid = t.uniqueid);
```